# Fourier Transform of the following L2 function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ function
$$h(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\dfrac{(x-i)^k}{(x+i)^{k+1}}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Recall that we may define the *Fourier transform* $\mathcal{F}: L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by letting $$\mathcal{F}[f](\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-i x \xi} dx$$ on $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and extending by continuity.

I want to compute the Fourier transform of $h$, but have been unable to perform the integration.

By the statement of the problem, I know that this Fourier transform should be zero a.e. on the positive real line, when $k \geq 0$ (a fact I have not been able to show either).

Any ideas how to tackle the problem?

**Edit**: Here $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ are equivalence classes of functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing
$$
             \frac{1}{x+i} = -i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{it(x+i)}dt,\;\;\; x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Then differentiate $k$ times with respect to $x$:
$$
     (-1)^k\frac{k!}{(x+i)^{k+1}}=-i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{it(x+i)}(it)^{k}dt \\
     \frac{1}{(x+i)^{k+1}}=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{itx}e^{-t}(it)^{k}dt.
$$
Then you can write $(x-i)^{k}$ in powers of $(x+i)$:
$$
         (x-i)^{k}=(x+i-2i)^{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}{{k}\choose{n}}(x+i)^{n}(-2i)^{k-n}.$$
The function $h(x)$ is then seen to be the inverse Fourier transform of a function that vanishes on the negative real axis. So the Fourier transform of $h$ must vanish on the negative real axis, and the desired Fourier transform can be written as a finite sum of functions given above.